# Cross compile mosquitto with existing openssl version on armv7

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, mosquitto

I've (so far) failed to successfully cross compile mosquitto with TLS for an embedded armv7 device. Without TLS, cross compilation works fine.

Embedded Device Data:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 548.86
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpd32
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x3
CPU part        : 0xc08
CPU revision    : 2

Hardware        : Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
Revision        : 0000
Serial          : 0000000000000000

# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1i  8 Dec 2020
not available
platform: linux-armv4
options:  bn(64,32) rc4(char) des(long) idea(int) blowfish(ptr)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=0
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: random-device ( "/dev/urandom" "/dev/random" "/dev/hwrng" "/dev/srandom" )
```

From the embedded device distributor I've gotten the cross compiler, and installed on my machine:

```
$ mkdir /opt/advantech
$ cd /opt/advantech
$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/bbsmartworx/Toolchains.git
$ sudo dpkg -i Toolchains/deb/*.deb
### The cross compiler is saved under /opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi
```

Next, download the same version of OpenSSL as found in the embedded device (1.1.1i)

```
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz
$ tar xfz openssl-1.1.1i.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.1.1i
$ ./Configure linux-armv4 --cross-compile-prefix=/opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/bin/armv7-linux-gnueabi- --prefix=/opt/arm/v7/openssl/ --openssldir=/opt/arm/v7/openssl shared
### I have also tried using the options I got when doing "openssl version -a" on the embedded device,
### but the final result is the same..
### ./Configure linux-armv4 --cross-compile-prefix=/opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/bin/armv7-linux-gnueabi- --prefix=/opt/arm/v7/openssl/ --openssldir=/opt/arm/v7/openssl shared -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=0 -fPIC -pthread -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -O3
$ make
$ make install
$ cd /opt/arm/v7/openssl/bin/
$ file openssl
openssl: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.12.10, stripped
$ ls -la openssl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 eh eh 554356 Feb 19 09:36 openssl
### The file size on my machine does NOT matches the one on the embedded device:
$ ssh root@embedded-device
# ls -la /usr/bin/openssl
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        535796 Dec 17 10:36 /usr/bin/openssl
# exit
Connection to embedded-device closed.
```

Move OpenSSLs includes and libraries within the sysroot of cross compiler:

```
$ cd /opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib
$ sudo cp -P /opt/arm/v7/openssl/lib/libcrypto* .
$ sudo cp -P /opt/arm/v7/openssl/lib/libssl* .
$ cd /opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/include
$ sudo cp -r /opt/arm/v7/openssl/include/openssl .
```

Download mosquitto and cross compile it

```
$ wget https://mosquitto.org/files/source/mosquitto-2.0.7.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz mosquitto-2.0.7.tar.gz
$ cd mosquitto-2.0.7
$ make CC=/opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/bin/armv7-linux-gnueabi-gcc CXX=/opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/bin/armv7-linux-gnueabi-g++ AR=/opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/bin/armv7-linux-gnueabi-ar LD=/opt/toolchain/gcc-conel-armv7-linux-gnueabi/bin/armv7-linux-gnueabi-ld
$ file src/mosquitto
src/mosquitto: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.12.10, stripped
$ file lib/libmosquitto.so.1
lib/libmosquitto.so.1: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```

Transfer cross compiled mosquitto and lib to embedded device:

```
$ scp src/mosquitto root@embedded-device:/opt/mosquitto/bin/.
$ scp lib/libmosquitto.so.1 root@embedded-device:/usr/lib/.
$ ssh root@embedded-device
# cd /opt/mosquitto/bin/
# ./mosquitto
./mosquitto: symbol lookup error: ./mosquitto: undefined symbol: ENGINE_load_builtin_engines, version OPENSSL_1_1_0
```

As mentioned before, when I modify mosquitto's config.mk to not use TLS and TLS_PSK, it works correctly on the embedded device.

config.mk:

```
WITH_TLS:=yes        # when set to "no", no errors on embedded device
WITH_TLS_PSK:=yes    # when set to "no", no errors on embedded device
WITH_CJSON:=no       # is always set to no
```

How should I cross compile OpenSSL to 100% match the version installed on the embedded device?

Changing OpenSSL on embedded device is not an option.

Comment: 1 ) Do you have any [tls_engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277415/cross-compile-mosquitto-with-existing-openssl-version-on-armv7) statement defined in your `mosquitto-conf` file ? 2) what is the ouput for `ls -ail /usr/lib/engines-1.1` wheb executed on your target ? 3) did you try compiling mosquitto with `CFLAGS=-DOPENSSL_NO_ENGINE` ?

Comment: 1) yes. I've a bridge connection that connects via mqtts, port 8883.. I add there `bridge_cafile`, `bridge_certfile`, `bridge_keyfile` and have `bridge_insecure false`
2) `ls: /usr/lib/engines-1.1: No such file or directory`
3) It compiled.. mosquitto runs! Let me try the connection to 8883. (will write back as soon as my test is done)

Comment: HI @Frant the `CFLAGS=-DOPENSSL_NO_ENGINE` solved the problem! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am glad to hear that. In this case, if you don't mind, I will add an answer you may want to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) - this should not take long.

Comment: Yes.. please post the answer. Thanks again, you just made my weekend! (I've been struggling with cross compiler the last two days)

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, can you tell me brand/model of the SoC you are using in your target system ? No problem if you cannot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228960/discussion-between-nhosko-and-frant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your target may not have dedicated hardware for encryption, and you therefore may not have any `openssl` crypto-engine implementation available on your platform, nor a version of `openssl` compiled with support for crypto-engines.

You can check by executing `ls: /usr/lib/engines-1.1`, since this is the location specified in the output for the `openssl version -a` command you executed. If no dynamic libraries are present, or the directory does not exist, this is likely that you don't have any support for crypto-engines currently available on your system.

In this case, you will have to re-build `mosquitto` with the `CFLAGS=-DOPENSSL_NO_ENGINE` option, so that  `mosquitto` will not attempt to load any (non-existing) `openssl` crypto-engine at startup.